# StoreFront product pages: Turn the Short Description section into a kindred tab section

Tags: theme-development, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, core-modifications

In StoreFront how do I turn the Short Description section into a kindred tab section beside the Long Description, Additional Information and Review tabs?

[image]